# Mac AppStore rejection for writing to /private/var/run/utmpx?

Tags: macos, app-store

My app was rejected for a cryptic and confusing reason which I have no way to understand. I haven't written to this location (the sandbox would not allow it anyways) and opening files in write modes causing writing to that file doesn't make any sense to me.

Is there a way to monitor if your app is writing to a location or which files are being opened in which mode? I have access from the sandbox to all locations I write/read to so I don't understand why the mode even matters. Even if I change some code I don't have any way to verify if this file was written to so it's pretty much impossible for me to debug at this point.

Thanks for any ideas to help debug this.

> The application accesses the following location(s):
>
> '/private/var/run/utmpx'
>
> The majority of developers encountering this issue are opening files
>   in Read/Write mode instead of Read-Only mode, in which case it should
>   be changed to Read-Only.
>
> Other common reasons for this issue include:
>
> - creating or writing files in the above location(s), which are not valid locations for files to be written as stated in documentation
> - writing to the above location(s) without using a valid app-id as a container for the written files
>
> Please review the "File-System Usage Requirements for the App Store"
>   of Submitting to the Mac App Store for the locations apps are allowed
>   to write and for further guidance.

Comment: Are you using any third-party libraries that may be attempting to write to files outside the sandbox?

Comment: The program has some shell scripts that execute various unix commands but the sandbox never complained about them. How can is be tested if a child process is writing to /private/var/run/utmpx anyways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer was that the command "uptime" was writing to /private/var/run/utmpx. This simply means that calling uptime is not possible in a sanboxed app, making it yet another victim of the sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would follow [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxQuickStart/AppSandboxQuickStart.html) guide to ensure you have properly enabled the App Sandbox.

Here is what Apple describes this guide as (note the statement I bolded):

> In this Quick Start you get an OS X app up and running in a sandbox. ***You verify that the app is indeed sandboxed and then learn how to troubleshoot and resolve a typical App Sandbox error.*** The apps you use are Xcode, Keychain Access, Activity Monitor, and Console.

My understanding is that if the App Sandbox is not setup properly, you can not effectively ensure that your app is running properly within a sandbox.

Comment: If I knew this was a sandbox issue that would be useful but I don't even know that yet. They also stopped me from using com.apple.security.files.user-selected.executable yet the sandbox allows me to chmod files as executable even without this enabled. What they're basically saying is that executing shell scripts may be a problem but the sandbox won't tell you.

Answer (score 0):

The file you referenced typically stores login/logout information for users.  If your app is invoking a command as user other than itself or escalates privileges to another user, this will occur as a write operation.  You should be careful to not invoke a secondary process causing a login write to that file (breaking sandbox)

Please see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utmp for information on this file

Comment: Interesting clue. thanks. I'm just running these scrips using NSTask and executing commands in PHP scripts using exec. There isn't even a way for me to invoke a command as another user that I'm aware of. I'm getting some sandbox errors in the console that appear to not affect the app running but maybe I just need to fix those anyways since I have no idea what is writing to that location.